# Cant Authenticate Single Tenant Angular Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an angular application that should authenticate with MS Azure AD single Tenant App which should be used only in one organization. Below are the configs which I have tried

```
auth: {
      clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
      //  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID',
      //authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:6735'
    },
```

All thes above ways of authority I have tried. It goes to the login page of Microsoft but after giving correct credentials it redirects with some code in the URL and login doesn't happen.

> `http://localhost:6735/#code=0.ASgAmOTRM_cEXkaKjvmSz2YuZyqUYHleyNlFoNYtQ5kOUEUAAAA.AQABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrHDMc_BSj9GrzkrZl2zT2QVp1Hml8h7qs1PSWM_umvMyKRk5U0C7IbDSpdEpL9SGjWzBFHBXBXh10eLEioVh1N8-hXeNyfLJFSqXShYPooCX8UnlUnIQqgFhULy_o1f7ybLLbMELBomOnJZQKZuJoxj6UJgtERnAE1TZ5-nx4YkPHSrlOD5aYSF6Pziu2Xfh8UOMArIUMAoXe_RUoqULKSIHFsxXypPpCNDo1ddWsxId96BbDdPhHix2IWCuz3SNtKC6i_22qiQSxHJnT3NlcoxyMS0-9f9tSMSEOmrzCU0y5mbuw7-OGYPO8Na3juGParCuPQhE7ZJyXcwFkKodEdGs-C1U-f5Bc_imtik4B8x6sRB2pa-DOAueRQHsLdUUBQn6w5xRmZ97KKXxuL0A59EHbNhNu59EFoVJB6zTTT3hBHLFg7qL9g2nkfZLAlfpp9IfqnsoZVl9xT0CIbl7NvsRFnjpsyp6Sw4oFvyEHiXuRvKLkl3Jz8O56PJody2hHEeqXuQvnWbZ9nk00MPOvArQ7bKyoCusCPQQp64uoPSLW9G389a3ihHLiiNlzJik2dHWjez2wBpSPwZCOingPRi3Mtkh5pIbxfijejQmWZlXB_wf_GaNPYPGNRXYygeo-2OZ9koWDKhQ5S6GP5ktjGPfDtlh6EJNCHAIuuHbK2IN2vjbxdO4_YVLX1NKq0Hh51B4-zNdsiFlZuVsy5RyA3ZQZGsnR1NIKV_wm5jMmdDsgAA&client_info=eyJ1aWQiOiJlYzczZDQ5OS1iYzFiLTRhZWUtYjMyZi0xYjlmOTMyODRiNjAiLCJ1dGlkIjoiMzNkMWU0OTgtMDRmNy00NjVlLThhOGUtZjk5MmNmNjYyZTY3In0&state=eyJpZCI6IjY3YWVjYjVkLWE5YjUtNDBhMy1iZDE5LWRmYmNmNjcxNTkwZiIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0=&session_state=9e6ae9e7-45ae-4fee-b4b2-921f628093ec`

Comment: For single tenant authority must be --https:/ /login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID. If it is SPA, please check if you have selected platfom as SPA in app registration in portal and give the redirect uri (-http:/ /localhost:4200/--) or( --http:/ /localhost:6735/--) (slash at the end)and make sure you configured the same uri in the application code or just (redirecturi:'/'). and try again .

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of the below is your workaround

1. If your application audience is a single tenant, you must provide an authority with your `tenant id` as you tried first:

```js
 auth: {
        clientId: 'your_client_id',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_tenant_id}'
         }
        };
```

2. By default, MSAL is configured to set the redirect URI to the current page that it is running on. If you would like to receive the authorization code on a different page than the one running MSAL, you can set this in the configuration. Any redirect URI used must be configured in the portal registration
3. If it is SPA, please check if you have selected platfom as SPA in app registration in portal and  check the URIs type in the manifest file to be Spa . Make sure you do not have multiple platforms configured in azure (for eg both SPA & Web App for same localhost uri).
4. Try to give the redirect uri  like this with **‘/’** at the end :http://localhost:4200/ or http://localhost:6735/ or redirecturi:'/' and make sure you configured the same uri in the application code and try again .
5. Make sure your client id and tenant id are given correctly. Local host is probably used while in development.If it still doesn’t work configure with https scheme in redirect uri in both app and in portal.

**Reference:**

1. [AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js (github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/initialization.md#optional-configure-redirect-uri)
2. [Quickstart:  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code-angular#register-and-download-your-quickstart-application)